# Are there any precision examples of telekinesis in Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars

I was in a chat room discussing who would win in a fight between Andrew from the recent movie *Chronicle* and a young Anakin Skywalker. They trumped me by saying that the SW characters never used TK with as much precision as Andrew, like ripping teeth out of a mouth. Once again Wookieepedia has failed me. Does anybody know of examples of precision telekinesis used in Star Wars canon?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Jedi Healer [Cilghal](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Cilghal) saved Mon Mothma's (at the time, Chief of State of the New Republic) life after Ambassador Furgan from Carida poisoned her with a "nano-destroyer" poison, by **extracting - with the help of the Force - the nanoparticles one by one**.

I think this is a wee more precise than moving a tooth :)

Comment: Also, Yoda did tell you "Size matters not!" :)   Actually, I vaguely remember that exact line being used by Luke on Cilghal to help her figure out how to heal Mon Mothma

Answer (score 4):

The force can affect individual molecules. As a concrete example, take the [sith mask technique](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mask_%28Sith_Alchemy%29):

> A Sith Alchemist could use the Mask to literally reshape an individual's appearance, altering a body at the molecular level.

I'm quite certain there are other examples in the Star Wars extended universe, but I don't have my books here to find them.

Comment: If someone wants to look up the final battle between Jacen Solo and Onimi, I believe that might mention it.

Answer (score 4):

Anakin Skywalker does a fair bit of precision when he uses TK to cut up the <s>apple</s> pear and move a piece to Amidala in the films.

Answer (score 2):

Disney Canon:

The construction of a lightsaber requires pinpoint precision, as seen in the Clone Wars episode,

**"The Gathering"**

Additionally, Luke addresses the skill required in the Force when constructing a lightsaber in the new canon book **"Heir to the Jedi"**:

> aligning those crystals by hand would be impossible - I sensed that it
>   had to be done with the Force, and only through the Force would I know
>   whether it was aligned properly or not. They were wafer-thin slices of
>   crystal, too, a beautiful clear amethyst, and might scratch or cloud
>   with handling. Moving them precisely with the Force would ensure that
>   they remained pristine.